# Making a customer feedback in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to gather feedback on the service provided.

In my view I have the following:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="entryForm">
  <div class="panel-body text-center">
   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
    <li class="list-group-item">
     <input type="button" name="feedback" value="1" class="btn btn-info">
     <input type="button" name="feedback" value="2" class="btn btn-info">
     <input type="button" name="feedback" value="3" class="btn btn-info">
     <input type="button" name="feedback" value="4" class="btn btn-info">
     <input type="button" name="feedback" value="5" class="btn btn-info">
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </form>

 <div class="panel-footer text-center">
  <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
   Submit
  </button>
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
    public function index(){
        $feedback = $this->input->post('feedback');
        $this->Feedback_model->addFeedback($feedback);
        $this->load->view('feedback/header');
        $this->load->view('feedback/survey');
        $this->load->view('feedback/footer');
    }
```

---

In my model I have the following:

```
  public function addFeedback($feedbackData){
    var_dump($feedbackData);
  }
```

---

I have a js file that responds to the button click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#submit").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#entryForm").submit();
 });
```

});

I just want to get the value of the button.

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: Your form is missing an 'action' attribute and there does not seem to be any 'submit' button either.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm getting NULL.

Comment: change `type="button` to `type="submit"`, did that fix your issue?

Comment: @DFriend action attribute is not required if the form is posting to the same page the form is on.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I had a submit button, see my new edited view code. I have id="submit", it should work?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, You are correct and am aware of that. But there is not enough code shown to know it that is the case. Oh wait... the OP just updated with an edit showing the button. But we're still forced to assume that posting to the same page is intentional.

Comment: @DFriend Now that you mention it, how does the framework know to load `index()` when a form is posted to the page?

Comment: Or, if more than one item can be selected use`<input type="checkbox" name="feedback[]"  ...`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, If the url is only the controller name,  i.e. `http://example.com/somecontroller` then `index()` is called by default.

Comment: @JasLamba, What is the function that loads the `<form>` the first time?

Comment: @JasLamba, A "submit" button must be `<button type="submit"...>` for a standard form to be... well, submitted unless you are using JavaScript to respond to button clicks. Are you using JavaScript that way?

Comment: @DFriend yes I have a JS file the responds to the button clicks.

Comment: In that case, you should add that code to your question.

Comment: @DFriend see edited code in the question.

Comment: Any JS code for the buttons in the list?

Comment: @DFriend nope no JS file for the buttons. I don't see why I would need to do that.

Comment: Me either. But I wanted to make sure. You're using the JS for the submit button because you moved it outside the `<form>` block, correct?

Comment: @DFriend Yes exactly.

Comment: Using a `<button>` for the feedback options is likely the wrong choice. You should use `type=radiobutton` if only one option is allowed or `type=checkbox` if you allow multiple options.

Comment: @DFriend Yes you are possibly right. If I use radio buttons it works perfectly. Seems to be the issue with the a button input. I don't understand why though.

Comment: Because `type='button'` has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts (javascript) associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur but its "value" is not "submitted".

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you:**

*1. Change your button type to submit and give a name and value to it like this :*

```
<div class="panel-footer text-center">
   <button type="submit" name='action' value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
   Submit
  </button>
</div>
```

*2.Your submit button should be inside `form` tag*

*3. For feedback form, your button type should be a `radio` or a `checkbox` and by default one of them should be `checked`*

**The whole form should be like this :**

Form action should have URL like this `action="<?=site_url('welcome/index');?>"` where `welcome` is your controller name
change it if welcome is not your controller:

```
<form action="<?=site_url('welcome/index');?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="entryForm">
  <div class="panel-body text-center">
   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
    <li class="list-group-item">
     <input type="radio" name="feedback" value="1" class="btn btn-info" checked>
     <input type="radio" name="feedback" value="2" class="btn btn-info">
     <input type="radio" name="feedback" value="3" class="btn btn-info">
     <input type="radio" name="feedback" value="4" class="btn btn-info">
     <input type="radio" name="feedback" value="5" class="btn btn-info">
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

 <div class="panel-footer text-center">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" name="action" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
   Submit
  </button>
 </div>
   </form>
```

*Your controller's `index` should be like this:*

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->input->post('action') === 'submit')
    {
        $feedback = $this->input->post('feedback');
        echo $feedback;
        die;
        $feedback = $this->input->post('feedback');
        $this->Feedback_model->addFeedback($feedback);
    }

    $this->load->view('feedback/header');
    $this->load->view('feedback/survey');
    $this->load->view('feedback/footer');
}
```

Comment: Its not a matter if the the form works or not. The works as I have it set up presently. If I change my input from a button to a normal text field it will capture it correctly. However, when I change the input type to button than that value corresponding with the button is not captured.

Comment: so , is my answer helpful to you or not

Comment: Its kind of helpful. If I replace <input type="button" with <input type="radio" then yes it works.

Comment: i not change your input to normal text because you can not use text input for the feedback  form radio type is more suitable

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to upvote and check it my answer as green